# MySQL - Left join with condition on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have those two tables:

T1:

```
id | bookable
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 0
4  | 1
5  | 0
```

T2:

```
id | t1_id
1  |   2
2  |   2
3  |   3
4  |   4
5  |   2
```

and I'd like to select rows of t1 that have "bookable" to 1 OR at least one corresponding value in t2.t1_id

With my example, this would be the result:

```
t1.id => 1,2,3,4
```

I have tried some requests with "left join", "count", "having" & "group by" but I can't get the result I want :(

All help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: @lurket, I used group by to have only 1 result per id, it works with your query! I have just added "GROUP BY t1.id"
Thanks, first time I see "NOT" and "ISNULL".
Can you post an answer so I can mark that as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `id` in the joined table is no longer unique, then `GROUP BY` does/can come into play. With the `LEFT JOIN`, the condition that `t1.id` exists in the `t1_id` column of the joined table is that either of the `t2` attributes (`t2.id` or `t1_id`) are not NULL:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1_id = t1.id
    WHERE bookable = 1 OR NOT ISNULL(t2.id)
    GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As lurker said You're not trying to COUNT or GROUP BY anything.
Try this

```
     select t1.* 
     from t1 left join t2
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id
     where t1.bookable = 1
     or t1.id in (select t2.t1_id from t2)
```